# Combination of versions that will build crosswalk cordova plugin for android 4.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

I want to give support to Android 4.0 using the crosswalk cordova plugin. The problem is that crosswalk stopped giving support for that version of Android, nevertheless in [this post](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/deprecate-40.html), they communicate that it is possible to run crosswalk in Android 4.0 through the version 19 of crosswalk which is the version 1.8.0 of the crosswalk cordova plugin.

Nevertheless, that cordova plugin version of crosswalk doesn't build with recent versions of cordova. The question is what versions of cordova, cordova-android (the platform) and Android API level will build for crosswalk cordova plugin 1.8.0 which will run on Android 4.0 (API level 14)?

I know the easy way is just to stop giving support for those versions but that would mean to lose a few clients and we don't want that if there is way to get around that. Also, the newer the version the bigger the APK package will be and therefore the more they are reluctant to install an App. For those reasons, it would be better to use older versions.

I have done a research on the subject and I found the combination of versions that will build and support Android 4.1 (API level 15 and up). the combination is:

```
#if you have cordova installed, you will need to uninstall first
npm uninstall -g cordova

npm install -g cordova@7.0.1

cordova platform add android@6.2.3

# The previous combination of versions will build the newest version of crosswalk (2.4.0)
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Build cordova using the Android API level 26, not newer because at this moment it doesn't build with API 28